# Triggering Tablesorter to maintain sorting when an entry is inserted into the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a table that is using table-sorter and while the sorting is working correctly, I have come across a case when the table becomes out of order.  That is, when an entry is added to the table, the table is no longer ordered.  How can I trigger table-sorter to maintain it's current sorting state (i.e., ascending, descending) with a click handler.

Currently, I am writing my own sorting algorithm to handle for this particular case, but it seems like it may be a wasted effort if a table-sorter solution exists.

```
addEntry.click(function() {
    // code that triggers the sort again
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [sortlist](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortlist) property when initializing the widget and trigger [addRows](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#addRows) after adding the new row.

In any case you may always trigger a click event on the table header for the column you need to sort.

The snippet:

```js
//
// set sort on first column in descending order and 
// on second column in ascending order
//
$("#myTable").tablesorter({ sortList: [[0,1], [1,0]] });
$('#addNewRow').on('click', function(e) {
    var newRow = $('<tr><td>z</td><td>a</td></tr>');
    $("#myTable tbody").append(newRow).trigger('addRows', [newRow, true]);
});

$('#sortOnFirstCol').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#myTable th:first").trigger('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/css/theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<button id="addNewRow">Add new Row</button>
<button id="sortOnFirstCol">Sort on first column</button>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bach</td>
        <td>Frank</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>Jason</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Conway</td>
        <td>Tim</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```